# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO28P0

Tags: java, nashorn, invokedynamic, methodhandle

I finished a library for Java and I used it to replace `java.lang.invoke` package (i.e., add it to the boot class loader prior to normal JVM library). In the package, it dynamically generates bytecodes for method handles. Thanks if you have any information about this class !

Currently, this package runs OK with JRuby with test cases, but it fails when I try to test it with Nashorn (A Java version for JavaScript language). The error message is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO28P0
    at java.lang.invoke.DYNGuardWithTestHandle702.0000000051119BF0.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at code.jit.asm.plugins.MethodHandlePlugin.initObject(MethodHandlePlugin.java:208)
    at code.jit.asm.backplane.ClassContext.createTransformedObject(ClassContext.java:359)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator$6.action(BytecodeGenerator.java:211)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator.run(BytecodeGenerator.java:325)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator.generate(BytecodeGenerator.java:291)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator.startGenerating(BytecodeGenerator.java:257)
    at code.jit.asm.services.TaskRepositoryService.put(TaskRepositoryService.java:48)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator.generate(BytecodeGenerator.java:251)
    at code.jit.asm.services.BytecodeGenerator.generate(BytecodeGenerator.java:247)
    at java.lang.invoke.CallSite.jitMethodHandle(CallSite.java:125)
    at java.lang.invoke.MutableCallSite.setTarget(MutableCallSite.java:116)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.ChainedCallSite.relinkInternal(ChainedCallSite.java:209)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.ChainedCallSite.relink(ChainedCallSite.java:161)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.LinkerCallSite.relink(LinkerCallSite.java:154)
    at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:297)
    at java.lang.invoke.DirectHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_L(DirectHandle.java:291)
    at java.lang.invoke.DYNFoldNonvoidHandle699.00000000525AABE0.inlinedMethod(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.invoke.MutableCallSiteDynamicInvokerHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(MutableCallSiteDynamicInvokerHandle.java:56)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$4$richards.:program(file:/C:/sxu/project/octane/richards.js:515)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:635)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:506)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:405)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.evaluateSource(Context.java:1236)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.load(Context.java:849)
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.load(Global.java:1544)
```

For the exception, I can not find any class JO28P0 from nashorn package. I can not get any information for this class via google.

Here the JS is from octane benchmark, in which I comment all tests except the the first two cases:

```
C:\\sxu\\project\\octane\\run.js
var base_dir = 'C:\\sxu\\project\\octane\\';
load(base_dir + 'base.js');
load(base_dir + 'richards.js');/*
load(base_dir + 'deltablue.js');
...
load(base_dir + 'typescript-compiler.js'); */
```

And the main Java code to launch the case is:

```
public static void runOctane(String[] args) {
    NashornScriptEngine nashorn = (NashornScriptEngine) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        CompiledScript scr = nashorn.compile(new String(Files.readAllBytes(
                Paths.get("C:\\sxu\\project\\octane\\run.js"))));
        scr.eval();

}
```

One VM argument is `-Djit_bytecode=true`. If this argument is true, then will go to my library. Otherwise, the my library would not be effect.

The exception disappears if `jit_bytecode` is false.

---

**UPDATE:**

My code emits dynamic bytecodes, which contains symbol `JO28P0`. The exception was thrown when I am trying to use `UNSAFE.defineAnonymousClass()`. So How  can I use use the Structure ClassLoader so that the `Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass` can succeed?

Comment: Did you compare the launching args between the two?

Comment: Yes. There is nothing nashorn related VM arguments in the command. The only change for VM args is the value of `-Djit_bytecode`

Comment: Try to launch both jvms in verbose mode and compare the messages to see if there are differences

Comment: jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO28P0 is one of those dynamically generated classes by nashorn. It is loaded StructureLoader. Nashorn itself is loaded by extension/platform class loader. But nashorn creates StructureLoader and ScriptLoader to load dynamically generated classes. Most likely the classloader you're using does not "see" these generated classes. See if you can use super class jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.JO (in general try if you can reflectively walk use a "visible" supertype in your generated class). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @A.Sundararajan explaination. So what should I do for my Unsafe.defineAC, so that it can resolve the classes `JO**` that are loaded by one/multiple `StructureLoader ` and `ScriptLoaders`?

Comment: Unsafe? I'd not recommend that ;)